# How to display CSS property "position : fixed" in same position in different screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, angularjs

I have a scenario, where the radio buttons in my screen need to display in table row where the table columns are scrollable and when the user is scrolling the content in the table the radio buttons need to display in the same position but in different resolutions the radio buttons are displaying in different position as i'm using position fixed property. 
Help me in handling the situation.

```
    <div style="right: 890px; top: 172px; position: fixed; color: white;">
       <input data-ng-repeat-start="data in radiovalues" id="Adj" value="{{data.radiovalue}}" type="radio" name="bill_type" style="margin-left: 12px;" />
    <span data-ng-repeat-end for="{{data.radiovalue}}">
      <b>{{data.radiovalue}}</b>
        </span>
</div>
```

expecting my code to work in different resolutions

Comment: IMO, the best way to handle different screen widths is to bootstrap the page up

Comment: Can you share the complete code which displays current behavior - and share the expected behavior also?